# Algorithm for web crawler in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, recursion

I'm trying to create an algorithm to do web crawling recursively and in a functional way.
I know how to do it using for loops, var variables, and accumulating on it.
But I'm struggling to do it recursively.

Some questions about my code: 
1. Why does `def loop` return  `Any`?
2. There are some URL in the form http://..../example.zip where getLinksPage throws an exception, returns None and breaks the loop. How can I deal with it?
3. How can I test this code with some Scala framework test?

```
 def getLinksPage(urlToCrawl: String): Option[List[String]] = {
    try {
      val conn = Jsoup.connect(urlToCrawl)
      val doc = conn.get()
      val elements = doc.select("a[href]")
      val elementsSc = elements.asScala
      val links = elementsSc.map(_.attr("abs:href")).toSeq
      val linksURL = links.map(new URL(_))

      val tartgetURL = (new URL(urlToCrawl)).getHost
      val linksLocalURL  = linksURL.filter(_.getHost == tartgetURL).map(_.toString).toList
      Some(linksLocalURL)
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => None
    }
  }

  def loop(l:Option[List[String]], acc: List[String]): Any = l match {
    case Some(Nil) => acc
    case Some(hd::tl) => if (!acc.contains(hd))   loop(getLinksPage(hd),hd::acc)
                        else  loop(Option(tl), acc)
    case None => acc

  }

 loop(getLinksPage(mainURL), List(mainURL))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You've explicitly set the return type to Any.  Update it to be `List[String]`
2. Reduce the scope of your exception handling to only include the code which may throw an exception.  Using a `for comprehension` should facilitate this.  Also for simplicity, consider just returning a `List` rather than an `Option[List]` using `List[String].empty`.
3. Two potential options: Mix-in your `conn` instance via a trait which will allow you to override the value or change your function to take an implicit `conn` which your unit tests can then mock.

**Edit**

Here is a spitball sample of how you can test your `getLinksPage` and `loop` functions as independent units using `ScalaTest`.  Disclaimer: syntax may not be 100%; adapt as needed.

```
case class Crawler() {
  def getConnection(url: String) = Jsoup.connect(url)

  def getLinksPage(urlToCrawl: String): Option[List[String]] = {
    val conn = getConnection(urlToCrawl)

    ...
  }
}

class CrawerSpec extends WordSpec with MockFactory {

  trait LinksFixture {

    val connection = mock[Connection]
    val getConnection = mockFunction[String, Connection]

    lazy val crawler = new Crawler() {
      override def getConnection(url: String) = LinksFixture.this.getConnection(url)
    }
  }

  trait LoopFixture {

    val getLinksPage = mock[String, Option[List[String]]]

    lazy val crawler = new Crawler() {
      override def getLinksPage(url: String) = LoopFixture.this.getLinksPage(url)
    }
  }

  "getLinksPage" should {

    "return the links" in new LinksFixture {

      val url = "http://bad-wolf"

      getConnection expects(url) returning connection
      // add other expects on connection

      crawler.getLinksPage(url) shouldBe expected // define expected
    }
  }

  "loop" should {

    "loop over the links" in new LoopFixture {

      getLinksPage expects(*) onCall {
        _ match {
          case "a" => Some(List("b","c"))
          case "b" => Some(List("d"))
          case _ => None
        }
      }
      // add any other expects

      crawler.loop(Some(List("a")), List.empty[String]) shouldBe // define expected
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Regarding point 3, how can I mock a web server locally with recursive http links to test the web crawler? Which framework (ScalaMock ...) ?

Comment: Updated answer with example unit test.  Not guaranteed to be syntactically correct. :)

Comment: I don't understand why you use this traits. And it's not working for me. I replicated your code with mine in Edit 2 and it's not working

Comment: What if any errors are you getting? When testing, my preference is to setup my code in test using fixtures which can be mixed into each individual test.  This allows me to reuse the same fixture when testing different inputs/outputs.

Comment: I've posted my code replicating your trait that is giving me errors.

Comment: You need to check the mocked function directly, not via the object.  Change `(foo.increment _) expects (12) returning (13)` to `increment expects (12) returning (13)`

Comment: Thanks. It works as you say, but why this other exact code Edit 3 is failing?

Comment: Your edits are being rejected.  As your question is now evolving, I'd suggest closing this question and creating a new one with your code sample and error.